# Is a $1_A \otimes U$ invariant subspace of $\mathcal{H}_A \otimes \mathcal{H}_B$ a product $V_A \otimes \mathcal{H}_B$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, oa.operator-algebras

Consider a subspace $V$ of $\mathcal{H}_A \otimes \mathcal{H}_B$, with $\mathcal{H}_A$ and $\mathcal{H}_B$ finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces, that is $1_A \otimes U$ invariant for all unitary operators $U$ on $\mathcal{H}_B$. Is $V = V_A \otimes \mathcal{H}_B$ for some subspace $V_A$ of $\mathcal{H}_A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action of $1_A\otimes U$ on $V$ defines the action of the unitary group $U(H_B)$ on $V$. This action induces the action of Lie algebra $\mathfrak{u}(H_b)$ on $V$. The action has the form $1\otimes T$ for skew-hermitian $T$. Every operator on $H_B$ has the form $T_1+iT_2$ for $T_1,T_2$ skew-hermitian, so we deduce that the subspace $V$ closed under the action of $1\otimes S$ for any operator $S$. It follows that $V=V_A\otimes H_B$ for some $V_A\subset H_A$.

It seems like we can also directly use the fact, that unitary operators span the vector space of all operators.